# Google Map API V3: How to disable vegetation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

While everyone is trying to add better vegetation image to google map, I need a clean geography without any vegetation and terrain information on it, which was done by API V2

Currently I have javascript:

```
var styles = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -80 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road.arterial",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffee" },
      { saturation: 50 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "poi.business",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.4335235),
    zoom: 3,
    styles: styles
};
```

This can return me a gray color image, but it still has vegetation and terrain on it. I failed to find a style type or anything else related to my problem. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Code

JSON (put it in your `styles` array):

```
{
    "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
    "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
},{
    "featureType": "landscape.natural.landcover",
    "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
},{
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
},{
    "featureType": "water",
    "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
}
```

## What it does

Completely removes:

- Natural terrain
- Natural landcover
- Parks (e.g. reserved forest lands)
- Water

## Preview

Before (default style):
[image: Google Maps default style]

After (custom style):
[image: Google Maps custom style]

Answer (score 0):

Since 2012, the default google map tiles have included terrain and vegetation:

> Google Maps now clearly shows terrain, color gradations to depict vegetation, and labels for natural land formations
>
> source: http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2012/10/get-better-view-of-natural-geography.html

As far as I know there there is no more basic map view than this. You can try OpenStreetMap tiles instead. OSM tiles provided by [CloudMade](http://wwww.cloudmade.com), for example, have fairly basic styling.

Comment: I know google added vegetation and terrain info to map since 2012. I'm  using google map API along with its HeatMap api, and I really don't want to take a lot efforts to find out how to implement HeatMap in other maps. So I want to confirm if google map can disable those nice tiles.